# Understanding the { } /dev/null \; when using find with -exec

Tags: bash, unix, grep, find, exec

I am trying to understand this line:

```
find $HOME -name "*.c" -exec grep "find this string" {} /dev/null \;
```

I understand the majority of it, but I am not sure about the `/dev/null` that appears after the `{}` and before the `;`.

`find` locates every C program file, and then for each file, `grep` looks for the line that contains the string... and then is it sending all the errors to `/dev/null`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be sending anything to `/dev/null`, it gives it as the second argument to grep, and grep will never find anything there. As it is, it has no effect, in my opinion.

Comment: that's strange because it is in the Unix textbook i got for school

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's used to force grep to print the matching file name, only useful in greps that don't have a specific option to do so. Look:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3

$ grep 2 file
2

$ grep 2 file /dev/null
file:2
```

It used to be required to get that output but with GNU grep (and others?) these days you can do this instead:

```
$ grep -H 2 file
file:2
```

You may want to check the sell-by-date on your text book ;-).

Comment: Very nice answer with the explanation. I thought POSIX `grep` had an option for this, but `-l` is the file name *only*, not the match as well. The textbook should definitely explain why `/dev/null` is passed as an argument, since it is basically only being used to trigger a side effect.